# What does "子役の闇" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, words, usage

a few days ago I find out that the term "子役の闇" exist, but I can't quite understand its meaning. I have seen it used on places like twitter and 2ch but it seems there's no English equivalent for this. I guess a literal translation would be something like "The desperation of the child actor" or something along those lines but I'm not sure about it and I don't think it makes much sense in English.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: That is nothing unique to the Japanese-speaking world. Have you not heard of Macaulay Culkin or Gary Coleman?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

闇{やみ} is often colloquially used to mean "deep, dark secrets"."unknown, unseen side (negative)" or "the dark side".

So in your example, 子役{こやく}の闇{やみ} means the "the dark side of child actors". People would use that when discussing bad things happening in the child actor industry.

There is also a term [N]の闇{やみ}が深{ふか}い, meaning [N] has some dark secret, or sometimes just that there is something doesn't seems quite right (and therefore there must be some deep, dark secret somewhere).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, "dark side" sounds good for what I have to do, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

'Child actors' very negative sides.'
I would translate like above.

闇 (darkness) in internet contexts often means very negative sides of something in contrast to its very positive sides.

Comment: So, in this case 闇 would simply refer to the downsides of being a child actor? Guess I was overthinking it, thank you.

Comment: Yup you are totally right.

Comment: @YuriMaker Personally, I wouldn't translate it to "downsides",. as that sounds too light.

Comment: As @Jimmy says, "downsides" is like "disadvantages", meaning not going to regular school, not having regular friends, dealing with the media exposure, etc. I think "negative" or "dark side" are best.